# Trying to install homebrew on Mac 11.0.1 Big Sur: curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I am trying to install Homebrew on Mac 11.0.1 Big Sur: I've installed Xcode via:

```
Xcode-select --install
```

And then tried running the latest homebrew package however it keeps returning the same error. Have tried restarting the computer, updating Xcode, changing the terminal command path bash to `/bin/ksh` and `/bin/zsh` and still no luck.

Is it possible to install homebrew another way other than the terminal?

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

```
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to the server
```

Comment: Download the file from your browser, save it somewhere locally and then `/bin/bash install.sh` it.